# Failed to convert parameter value from a Object to a boolean

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on an app in MS Azure using C#.  I thought I had an issue with my code until I went into SQL Management Studio and discovered that it may be with the structure.

I've got an account table:

```
id  uniqueidentifier    nonnull, default (newid())
Email   varchar(128)    null
FirstName   varchar(128)    null
LastName    varchar(128)    null
PhoneNumber varchar(50) null
createdAt   datetimeoffset(7)   Nonnull, default (sysutcdatetime())
updatedAt   datetimeoffset(7)   null
version timestamp   nonnull
deleted bit nonnull, default ((0))
```

When I right click on the table and select edit top 200 rows I get two rows that I entered to test.

If I try to make a change to any column, I get:

[image: sql error message]

And again, this is any column I try to edit.

I then clicked on the SQL button to show the SQL query that created the edit and started removing columns to figure out what is causing me issues.

If I removed the column "deleted" it will save the row's changes.  So I thought that was it.  However, I played around with it a while and discovered that if I remove createdAt and leave in deleted then it will work as well.

When I have both createdAt and deleted in the edit query then it doesn't allow me to save with the above message.

I can set the deleted flag by running a manual query:

```
Update Account set deleted='true' where id='[guid]'
```

Comment: check field datatype.

Comment: datatype is bit as specified as above

Answer (score 0):

This field accept only `0 or 1`

deleted bit nonnull, default ((0))

Comment: Even if I put a 0 or 1 in that column when in edit mode, it doesn't work.